# c# Сортировка вложенных списков, как?

Tags: c#, сортировка

Есть вложенный список

```
public Dictionary<dynamic, Dictionary<string, dynamic>> Data = new();
```

В него динамически добавляются данные такого рода:

```
Data .Add(ID, new Dictionary<string, dynamic> {
  { "Addr", Addr },
  { "Pos", Pos  },
  { "Description", Description },
  { "Number", Number  }
});
```

На выходе получаем примерный список:

```
Data["adx01"][{"Addr":5},{"Pos":100},{"Description":"Описание1"},{"Number":44}];
Data["vdx11"][{"Addr":2},{"Pos":45},{"Description":"Описание2"},{"Number":12}];
Data["ydx50"][{"Addr":3},{"Pos":67},{"Description":"Описание3"},{"Number":71}];
Data["zdx31"][{"Addr":10},{"Pos":9},{"Description":"Описание4"},{"Number":33}];
```

Мне нужно отсортировать его по полю "Number", чтобы было вот так:

```
Data["ydx50"][{"Addr":3},{"Pos":67},{"Description":"Описание3"},{"Number":71}];
Data["adx01"][{"Addr":5},{"Pos":100},{"Description":"Описание1"},{"Number":44}];
Data["zdx31"][{"Addr":10},{"Pos":9},{"Description":"Описание4"},{"Number":33}];
Data["vdx11"][{"Addr":2},{"Pos":45},{"Description":"Описание2"},{"Number":12}];
```

Каким методом это можно сделать?

Ответ:
aepot: Data=Data.OrderBy(pair => (int)pair.Value["Number"]).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)

Comment: `dynamic` зло и тормоз :) я удивлен что он вообще в качестве ключа к словарю подходит.

Comment: Теоретически так `Data.OrderBy(pair => (int)pair.Value["Number"]).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)`

Comment: Порядок элементов в словаре не определён.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ну да, с `ToDictionary` я перегнул :)

Comment: @aepot метод сработал! Спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а чем плох dynamic? у меня около 1000 записей данного типа, это сильно повлияет на скорость итераций? Где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: так вы потестируйте, лучший ответ - это свои результаты тестов, `dynamic` плох всем, это костыль, пришедший из слаботипизированных языков, и по факту он в серьезных проектах никогда не используется, у него нет плюсов.

Comment: @aepot был бы счастлив если Вы приведете пример как протестировать)
а если у меня поле может быть int/string/uint/ulong, как я могу заранее задать свойства в полях?
например vdx11 - ulong, впринципе можно указать его вместо dynamic, но в случае с другими полями Addr/Pos/Description не знаю как им задать заранее тип

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov а почему вложенный словарь нельзя сделать просто объектом/классом ? Как я вижу поля то все повторяются

Comment: Используйте разные модели данных, ключи в словаре не могут быть разных типов, точнее не сравниваемые друг с другом, в противном случае смысл словаря обнуляется. Словарь - для контроля уникальности ключей, в этом его смысл, а как контролить уникальность, когда невозможно один слкч с другим сравнить? Используйте тогда уж списки или массивы, научитесь классы писать для моделей данных. Примеров полинтернета.

Comment: @Archery тут скорее дело в необразованности и не понимании, как это сделать в с# грамотно и как оно должно выглядеть, листая интернет я замечаю только то, что мне знакомо, считай вижу кусты, а ягоды нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете модель данных

```
public class Item
{
    public long Addr { get; set; }
    public long Pos { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
}
```

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();

items.Add(id, new Item
{
    Addr = Addr,
    Pos = Pos,
    Description = Description,
    Number = Number
});
```

тогда отсортировать это можно так

```
var ordered = items.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.Number);
```

Сам по себе словарь не может считаться упорядоченной структурой данных, поэтому запихивать перечислитель `ordered` типа `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Item>>` обратно в словарь нет никакого смысла. И используйте для словаря строго типизированные ключи сравниваемого типа.

Comment: огонь) спасибо! буду изучать
меня привлек метод через словарь тем, что я могу напрямую обратиться к конкретному полю объекта
например Data["ydx50"]["Number"] и я сразу получу 71
можно ли так же явно получать значения полей используя Ваш метод?

Comment: Конечно можно ```Data["ydx50"].Number```.

Comment: @aepot а можно как то в public class Item объявить вызов метода? например что то типа 
`public class Item
    {
    public long Addr { get; set; }
    public long Pos { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public int GetPeriod(Addr)  { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: т.е. было бы круто например если у меня есть функция `GetPeriod(long Addr, bool customBool)` которую я бы смог вызывать так `int Period = Data["ydx50"].GetPeriod(true)`, где `Addr` брался бы из самого класса `Item`

Comment: получилось вот так, но не знаю так ли это делается:                                                      
`public bool Period (bool customBool)  {   return GetPeriod(Addr, bool customBool); }`

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov если у вас новый вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельно